# How good are VHDL's random numbers?

Tags: random, statistics, vhdl

I'm using VHDL's random numbers from `IEEE.math_real`, but how good are these generated numbers?

.... let's say compared to `rand(...)` from C.

Have there been statistical tests?

---

Here is a histogram of a Gaussian distribution. Parameters:

- Random source: 2 uniform distributed REAL values generated by `math_real.Uniform(...)`
- Box-Muller transformation
- calculated using REAL
- Output rang: 0..4095 INTEGER
- 102.400 iterations

Classic histogram view:
[image: NormalDistributedRandomValue 100Ki iterations; range 0..4095]

As a point cloud:
[image: NormalDistributedRandomValue 100Ki iterations; range 0..4095]

---

Here is a histogram of a uniform distribution. Parameters:

- Random source: uniform distributed REAL values generated by `math_real.Uniform(...)`
- calculated using REAL
- Output rang: 0..4095 INTEGER
- 102.400 iterations

Classic histogram view:
[image: NormalDistributedRandomValue 100Ki iterations; range 0..4095]

As a point cloud:
[image: NormalDistributedRandomValue 100Ki iterations; range 0..4095]

Gnuplot fitting results for `f(x)=m*x+b`:

```
m = -0.0000343906
b = 25.0704
```

In my opinion, both histograms have a high jitter.

Comment: Dear downvoter, would be great if you left a comment with reason for giving a downvote, so the question can be improved.

Comment: Could be interesting to make a chi-square test to see if the jitter/outliers are within reasonable range.

Comment: Is it possible to do such a test in Gnuplot? I'm still waiting for my uniform distribution to finish ... My current tests show that the weight center is not at 2048.

Comment: @MortenZilmer I added the uniform distribution histogram and fitted m*x+b to it. I'll try to do a Gaussian fit to the first image. Are you interessted in the dat files generated by VHDL?

Comment: Does it smooth out when the number of iterations is increased?

Comment: @MartinZabel No. I tested 1k, 10k, 100k and 1M iterations. The depicted images are based on 100k iterations. Gnuplot fits the mean value of the Gaussian distribution to 2068 instead of 2048.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of `IEEE.math_real.UNIFORM` is:

```
procedure UNIFORM(variable SEED1,SEED2:inout POSITIVE;variable X:out REAL) is
  ...
  variable Z, K: INTEGER;
  variable TSEED1 : INTEGER := INTEGER'(SEED1);
  variable TSEED2 : INTEGER := INTEGER'(SEED2);
begin
  ...

  K := TSEED1 / 53668;
  TSEED1 := 40014 * (TSEED1 - K * 53668) - K * 12211;
  if TSEED1 < 0  then
    TSEED1 := TSEED1 + 2147483563;
  end if;

  K := TSEED2 / 52774;
  TSEED2 := 40692 * (TSEED2 - K * 52774) - K * 3791;
  if TSEED2 < 0  then
    TSEED2 := TSEED2 + 2147483399;
  end if;

  Z := TSEED1 - TSEED2;
  if Z < 1 then
    Z := Z + 2147483562;
  end if;

  SEED1 := POSITIVE'(TSEED1);
  SEED2 := POSITIVE'(TSEED2);
  X :=  REAL(Z) * 4.656613e-10;
end UNIFORM;
```

With these description about implementation:

> a) The semantics for this function are described by the
>   algorithm published by Pierre L'Ecuyer in "Communications
>   of the ACM," vol. 31, no. 6, June 1988, pp. 742-774.
>   The algorithm is based on the combination of two
>   multiplicative linear congruential generators for 32-bit
>   platforms.
>
> b) Before the first call to UNIFORM, the seed values
>   (SEED1, SEED2) have to be initialized to values in the range
>   [1, 2147483562] and [1, 2147483398] respectively.  The
>   seed values are modified after each call to UNIFORM.
>
> c) This random number generator is portable for 32-bit
>   computers, and it has a period of ~2.30584*(10**18) for each
>   set of seed values.
>
> d) For information on spectral tests for the algorithm, refer
>   to the L'Ecuyer article.

The L'ecuyer paper is ["Efficient and portable combined random number generators"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234789148_L'ecuyer_P_Efficient_and_portable_combined_random_number_generators_Communications_of_the_ACM), as given by user1155120 in the comments.

So it is a [Combined Linear Congruential Generator (CLCG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combined_Linear_Congruential_Generator) using Wichmann/Hill/Schrage/Bratley et. al.'s method (see L'ecuyer paper) to avoid integer overflow when implemented using 32-bit integers.

It appears that the constants selected for the CLCG are well known, based on the Wiki and other references I could find by quick search.  As user1155120 informs in the comments, the random properties of the CLCG have been analyzed in ["A Comparison of Four Pseudo Random Number Generators Implemented in Ada"](http://actel.kr/_hdl/1/erm1.u-strasbg.fr/vhdl/misc/rnd_gene/random.pdf).

Based on this, it appears that the VHDL random generator is pretty solid, so I would expect that the jitter/outliers that you found are simply a result of the randomness.

Comment: ***How good are VHDL's random numbers?*** and you come up with 'pretty solid' and 'so I assume'?  As far as the Gaussian jitter, what method is being used to quantize a REAL output into a 4048 value integer?  The 1988 ACM [L’ECUYER](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Pierre_LEcuyer/publication/234789148_L'ecuyer_P_Efficient_and_portable_combined_random_number_generators_Communications_of_the_ACM/links/00b7d5282b5c3da8cb000000.pdf) paper mentioned in the math_real package declaration. It's been [tested](http://actel.kr/_hdl/1/erm1.u-strasbg.fr/vhdl/misc/rnd_gene/random.pdf) (in Ada).

Comment: Thanks for the references to L'ecuyers original paper, and the paper about testing, and I have updated the answer to include this and skip my assumption.